# Destination is not reachable directly and all routehints were unusable - how might I remedy that?

Tags: lightning-network, payment, core-lightning, lightning-routing, route-hints

After launching `lightningd` I get following:

```
2023-07-20T06:54:46.533Z UNUSUAL 038.............................................................8f--connectd: Feature 28 requires feature 20
2023-07-20T06:59:47.735Z UNUSUAL 038.............................................................8f--connectd: Feature 28 requires feature 20
2023-07-20T07:04:48.511Z UNUSUAL 038.............................................................8f-connectd: Feature 28 requires feature 20
```

Again, I replaced the digits of the amount with dots for the sake of privacy.
For the sake of avoiding privacy leak I replaced the characters of the long string with dots.

When trying to pay an invoice I get following from `lightning-cli`:

```
{
   "code": 210,
   "message": "Destination 03d..............................................fac is not reachable directly and all routehints were unusable.",
   "attempts": [
      {
         "status": "failed",
         "failreason": "Destination 03................................................fac is not reachable directly and all routehints were unusable.",
         "partid": 0,
         "amount": "7........0msat",
         "amount_msat": "7........0msat"
      }
   ]
}
```

My `bitcoin.conf` is

```
daemon=1
keypool=2
```

I get the same message from `lightning-cli` when `lightningd` is launched
over Tor.

Comment: Is your node new? Did you leave it running for some time after it got a connection? Try running `lightning-cli listnodes` and see if you get a big list of nodes out. If your node didn't catch-up with the graph, it can't route payments.

Comment: @DavidsonSouza `listnodes` returns two node ids: "02443262a10d7fd82415c428b615c85944e70cbb51504a65387ec50ebda26e9f8a" and "03864ef025fde8fb587d989186ce6a4a186895ee44a926bfc370e2c366597a3f8f".
My node has more than a year and I run it avery two months or so for a couple of days. Before posting this it has been up for four days. My `gossip_store` has 765 bytes, would removing it change anything?

Comment: That's why you can't pay. `listnodes` should return over a thousand nodes. I don't think there's a way to force `lightningd` to redownload gossip and deleting generated files isn't wise. You need to leave it running for a while to catch up the gossip announcements it missed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay the following features are regarding the dual funding protocol

```
2023-07-20T06:54:46.533Z UNUSUAL --connectd: Feature 28 requires feature 20
2023-07-20T06:59:47.735Z UNUSUAL --connectd: Feature 28 requires feature 20
2023-07-20T07:04:48.511Z UNUSUAL 038-connectd: Feature 28 requires feature 20
```

The change that is breaking your node is this one https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/5670 but I am not able to find your node version inside the post description so I do not know what it is happening in concrete. This happens because we are using an experimental feature and we are allowed to break experimental feature

BTW overall what is going on is that core lightning preserves your channel and gives you the opportunity to fix the error (some other implementation will close the channel in this case). So you are not able to pay the invoice because the channel should be disabled and your `listfunds` should have the `connected` set to false for the channel item.

To make this work you should fix the funding problem but this depends on your node status and requires more information to support you.